# How to find out with which language Telegram bot's API is written?

Tags: api, server, telegram-bot

Most of the Telegram bots has API behind them to interact with their users. Is there a way to recognize which programming language is used (PHP, Python, NodeJS, ...) for bot's API?

For example, this bot: @weatherman_bot

Comment: I used PHP for my bot's API and for push notification section, I read somewhere that PHP is not support to send notifications and it is old. Is it better to write it again with NodeJS?

Comment: I don't understand what that has to do with the question you asked.

Comment: Not by technical means. By the way don't believe everything you read.

Answer (score 1):

Most times some telegram (*tg*) bots have the code on github, you can just look through their code and from there know which language it was written in.

An example would be a todobot I made: `@my_todos_bot` the source code is available on [github](https://github.com/Rotimi-Best/mytodos). By the way the bot is currently active and working.

But basically knowing the language doesn't really determine how to bot will function because tg supports [lots of languages](https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples) from which you can choose from. I personally make mine in Nodejs but you can do it in whichever you choose (and is supported by tg).